# Error on writing a json formatter in a Play application

Tags: json, scala, playframework

i'm writing a Play 2.3.2 application in Scala.
I've write a class that represents the correlation between a category and an attribute in my system.
The class is declared like the following:

```
case class Correlation(val category: String, val attribute: String,
                  val value: Double, val weight: Double)
```

Now i'm writing a json formatter but i'm getting some errors.
The Formatter is write like the following:

```
object CorrelationFormatters {

   implicit val storageFormatter: Format[Correlation] = {     
   val correlationReads: Reads[Correlation] = (
       (__ "category").read[String] and
       (__ "attribute").read[String] and
       (__ "value").read[Double] and
       (__ "weight").read[Double]
       )(Correlation.apply _)

   val correlationWrites: Writes[Correlation] = (
        (__ "category").write[String] and
        (__ "attribute").write[String] and
        (__ "value").write[Double] and
        (__ "weight").write[Double]
        )(unlift(Correlation.unapply _))
   }


}
```

But i'm getting the following compiler errors:

```
error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/app/recommendationsystem/formatters/json/CorrelationFormatters.scala:19: ')' expected but string literal found.
[error]        (__ "category").read[String] and
[error]            ^
[error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/app/recommendationsystem/formatters/json/CorrelationFormatters.scala:31: ')' expected but '}' found.
[error]    }
[error]    ^
[error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/app/recommendationsystem/formatters/json/CorrelationFormatters.scala:19: ')' expected but string literal found.
[error]        (__ "category").read[String] and
[error]            ^
[error] /Users/alberto/git/bdrim/modules/recommendation-system/app/recommendationsystem/formatters/json/CorrelationFormatters.scala:31: ')' expected but '}' found.
[error]    }
[error]    ^
[error] two errors found
```

What's wrong??
I've used the ScalaJsonCombinators tutorial like example, but i can't find out where i'm wrong.

Comment: Remove `val` in case class. It is added by compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Try with:](http://playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonInception)

```scala
object Correlation {
  implicit val jsonModelReads = Json.reads[Correlation]
  implicit val jsonModelWrites = Json.writes[Correlation]
  implicit val jsonModelFormat = Json.format[Correlation]
}
```

And then `import Correlation._`

Comment: It compile, but how if works this code??
It create a json with the tag name equals to the class val??
In this case a json like {"category": "c", "attribute": "a", "value": 20, "weight": 2}?

Comment: It is scala macro, see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonInception

Comment: I didn't know the reads and writes macro.
This solution is best than the mine.
Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, the `reads` and `writes` are redundant if `format` is used. This also doesn't explain why the OP was getting the compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple fix:

```
 (__ "category").read[String]
```

should be

```
(__ \ "category").read[String]
```

And for all the other lines as well..